# Why is windows constantly reading my harddisk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

for the last 10 minutes or so my hard disk light is constantly on, but i am not really doing anything here that would require heavy disk access. After a bit of digging i could only find the "System" process doing a lot of reads and writes to "c:\System Volume Information\". From what i have just read, this is for system restore points and the indexing service, which i both turned off. Can anyone enlighten me what this does, or how to find out what windows  feature exactly is doing this, and how i can windows stop from doing it?
(edit: It stopped ... for now.)

a little background info:
This is a thinkpad T410 with 4GB ram and Win7 Pro (64Bit). I already disabled all the services i never need (printing, indexing, media center sharing, frikking "Windows is looking for a solution" thingy and whathaveyou). Windows and all the software i use is up to date with the latest patches. Im also quite sure it's not some virus or malware since i don't download any torrents or pirated software, and i know a dodgy site when i see one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a look at the timestamps of the system restore points (ccleaner->tools) it looks like windows decided to spontaneously create a new restore point just now... ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I usually disable restore points (at all, they are useless for many reasons), planned defrag, planned antivirus scan, file indexing (I never search): my system is faster and my hard disks last longer. I also recommend to set Windows Update to just warn you. If you have an SSD disk, also disable browser's DISK cache -- Just my 2c EDIT: sorry, I've just read the 2nd part of your question -- you already done many of these things

Comment: Yeah, i did that for the exact same reason, and in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System ->System Protection -> Configure ... the current "Restore settings" is "Turn off system protection" - so wtf?

Comment: I can't name how many times a restore point saved my bacon in Windows 7.

Comment: A restore point may have been created if some third party app decided to run its own auto updater: Adobe, Java, etc., although usually you would have to intervene to give it permission to install via UAC.

Comment: I can't count how many times restore points could have saved the countless users asking questions here.  But to each his own. I would ignore the browser disk cache advice though.  In theory, that actually SLOWS down you computer, as the browser forces pages out of memory to the paging file. At best, it will give you maybe a couple of months extra on the SSD?

Comment: @surfasb: in Firefox, memory cache is limited (i.e. it will trash older cache entries). If you refer to the web pages currently "open", then the probability of exceeding your memory is minor, and if you exceed it, then disk cache won't help. More, I have no paging file. I've got 8 GB RAM, and if they become full, for me the system may even crash since there's already something weird going on :)

Comment: I prefer "out of memory" rather than my HDD grumbling because of massive swapping activity

Comment: @Moab: if you draw on system restore, than your system is most likely deeply compromised by misconfiguration or other issues, and will turn into problems again, in the future. If, for example, the system is infected by a virus, I consider it 'not trusted' ANYMORE even if you use "system restore" to repair it and then run an antivirus scan with 0 viruses found.
The only valid "restore", to me, is restoring a ghost image or formatting and reinstalling. I don't like untrusted or prone-to-problems systems, which unfortunately are the most common around. :)

Comment: The proof is in the pudding. . .

Comment: @gd1, agree to disagree about your restore "opinion", This does not change how many times it has saved my butt. Ghost image can contain a virus also.

Comment: @Moab sure in fact it is just an opinion. Talking about the ghost image having viruses, it's just a matter of 'trusted' vs 'untrusted state'. If a system is in a trusted state than you just assume it hasn't any virus. It's you to decide the conditions under which the system is trusted, and it's not so easy to establish such policies. However many people (and, lastly, me) agree on the fact that when a system gets infected by a virus it becomes untrusted -- FOREVER. However, just for curiosity, can you tell me a circumstance in which system restore saved your butt? :)

Comment: (Other people for example consider a system to be 'untrusted' after the first time it runs an unsigned executable.)

Comment: @gd1, If I have to explain how it saved mu butt, then I am talking to an inexperienced user, a waste of my time. If the system is trusted then Restore or Image is safe, what is your point, oh, you don't have one, just another opinion.

Comment: I was kindly asking you to make me an example like "The fact X happened, and I had my butt saved thanks to system restore". The problem with System Restore vs Image Restore is that - for example - if a virus seizes the system, it might change the system in such a deep way, that system restore may not be working for you, but against you. However... it's ok, I give up - seems like I've become unpopular. Cheers.

Comment: The only time I needed a system restore it did not work and I had to re-install all windows and all softwares... Now I backup all my data (thanks to gdrive, dropbox and oneDrive) and rely only on virtual machines (backuped in external hdd)